# Multivariate (5 dependent 1 independent variable) and paired data, multiple samples used. Which statistical test?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, paired-data

My data has 5 dependent variables (measured amount of oxygen, halides, nitrogen, sulfur, and organic) and one independent variable with 2 "treatments (flow rate, 1 Lpm or 2 Lpm). The catch is: I have multiple pairs of data for 2 treatments, which are not for the same sample (each pair is its own sample, taken at a different date - see attached picture below).

I would like to evaluate if the flow rate treatment had a significant influence on the results of 5 dependent variables. Would be a classic MANOVA test if not for the fact that I want to know that across all pairs of data. Performing multiple MANOVAs for each pair is not useful because there is not enough measurements for each independent variable (i.e. 2-3 for each dependent variable for each treatment and date).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Data + Visualization]

Comment: The most appropriate analytical approach depends not just on the data, but also on the inferences that you might make and on what you might do in response to those inferences. What are you trying to achieve? Is this a preliminary study that will be followed with a designed study? Are you characterising an assay?

Comment: This is a completed study. We wanted to increase the flow rate from 1 Lpm to 2 Lpm without influencing the chemical composition of the measured dependent variables oxygen, halides, nitrogen, sulfur, and organics. So we want to know if this is true or not, namely if the 1 Lpm and 2 Lpm datasets are statistically different or equal. The eye test says equal, but this if of course not and inference based on statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not confident i know enough to help here, but i'm thinking MANOVA is for 3 or more groups - you just have two groups of scores - i'm thinking a series of Mann-Whitneys - what am i missing here?

Comment: MANOVA can also be done for 2 groups too (similarly as ANOVA can be done for 2 groups but then t-test is useful). The t-test equivalent for 2 groups with multivariate data would be Hotelling's T-test. At least that is what I remember.

Comment: Yea but that data doesn't look parametric, t-test and ANOVA are parametric tests i think. You could check if the data is parametric, but if not then i think you will end up with a series of Mann Whitneys, one for each dependent variable